# Resolving type when passed as a parameter in a method in Autofac/c# (Please check sample code)

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm using Autofac in .Net Core 2.1 application. I have a class with a method that instantiates a type directly using new keyword, and hence it is tied to a particular implementation. How could I resolve the type using Autofac instead of using new? The method creates an object of type Engine and adds it to a collection of type IEngine, where Engine implements IEngine. Therefore constructor or method resolving won't work.

Below is sample code:

```
public class Vehicle<T1> : IVehicle<T1>
{
    private Dictionary<string, IEngine<T>> Engines = new Dictionary<string, IEngine<T>>();

    public void Create(string id)
    {
        IEngine<T> engine = new Engine<T>();

        // use engine...

        Engines.Add(id, engine);
    }
}
```

As you can see Vehicle is tightly coupled to an implementation of IEngine. How can I use Autofac to dynamically resolve IEngine in this case? I think my problem is that I don't have a reference to the Autofac container. How do I get a reference to the container in a class like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to instantiate the engines using auto generated delegate factories in Autofac. You see, Autofac is able to do it automatically:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Vehicle<>)).As(typeof(IVehicle<>));
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Engine<>)).As(typeof(IEngine<>));
        var container = builder.Build();

        var vehicle = container.Resolve<IVehicle<object>>();
        vehicle.Create("1");

        Console.WriteLine(vehicle.EngineCount);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IVehicle<T>
{
    void Create(string id);

    /// <summary>
    /// This property is just for testing
    /// </summary>
    int EngineCount { get; }
}

public class Vehicle<T> : IVehicle<T>
{
    private readonly Func<IEngine<T>> _engineFactory;
    private Dictionary<string, IEngine<T>> Engines = new Dictionary<string, IEngine<T>>();

    /// <summary>
    /// This property is just for testing
    /// </summary>
    public int EngineCount => Engines.Count;

    public Vehicle(Func<IEngine<T>> engineFactory)
    {
        _engineFactory = engineFactory;
    }

    public void Create(string id)
    {
        IEngine<T> engine = _engineFactory();

        // use engine...

        Engines.Add(id, engine);
    }
}

public interface IEngine<T>
{
}

public class Engine<T> : IEngine<T>
{
}
```

Notice that I have changed a name of generic type parameter in type `Vehicle<>` from `T1` to just `T`, in order to make it correspond to the type parameter, that is used inside a class for `Engine<T>` instances. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be the solution, but unfortunately it's not working for me.. I'm getting an autofac exception that seems to be related to the Vehicle class not having a default constructor...

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed in Func<Engine<T>> instead of Func<IEngine<T>>... I will mark your solution.

Comment: Happy to help=)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to delegate the instantiation of Engine object to another class like Factory would help you to resolve IEngine to the wanted concrete engine class.

Also, you can use events here, so the Create method here is the trigger that you need an engine and on some other class by event/delegate you can resolve and pass to it the engine.